# Как открыть cmd.exe от системного пути?

Tags: c#

Всем привет!
Нужно, чтобы `cmd.exe` открывался по пути `"{Системный диск}\Windows\System32"`.
Т.е. вот так:

[image: {Системный диск}\Windows\System32]

Пробовал вот так: `Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");`, но всё ровно открывается по пути проекта *(exe файла, который я собрал)*, но с правами администратора. Т.е. вот так:

```
C:\Users\(Тут куча путей до проекта)\bin\Debug
```

Пробовал даже так - `Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/C \"cd \"C:\\Windows\\System32\"\"");`.

**Программа запускается от имени администратора, в манифесте прописано, что ей требуются права администратора.**

Comment: `CMD /k CD %systemroot%\system32`

Comment: @Akina, спасибо большое! Сделал так - `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k CD %systemroot%\\system32");` и всё заработало.

Comment: Чё б ему было не заработать-то...

Comment: @Akina ответом тогда может?

Comment: @tym32167 А смысл? `cmd /?` - и вот он, ответ, на экране, только прочитай... ценность ответа - нулевая.

Comment: @Akina так тут полно ответов, где было бы достаточно доку почитать. Так чтоне вижу ничего плохого в таком ответе. Ну или вопрос надо удалять, а то он так и повиснет.

Comment: @tym32167 несколько странно удалять вопрос только потому, что у него в комментариях есть полуответ с CD вместо нормального ProcessStartInfo. Два голоса за закрытие с левой причиной :( И минус. На вполне нормальном вопросе.

Comment: @Akina этот вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится или опечаткой? в чем опечатка?

Comment: @PashaPash Проблема не воспроизводится... если прочитать инструкцию. Ну или, если про опечатку, то ошибочное `/c` вместо `/k`.

Comment: @Akina какую инструкцию? кто-то дал топикастеру нормальное решение в комментариях? или вы про костыль с /k CD? завтра человеку надо будет другой процесс в папке запустить - и он вместо ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory начнет городить запуск через CMD с CD и цепочкой команд. Вопрос стоит закрыть, если на него нельзя дать нормальный ответ. А тут - вполне можно.

Comment: @PashaPash *или вы про костыль с /k CD?* Да, я именно про костыль. *Вопрос стоит закрыть, если на него нельзя дать нормальный ответ. А тут - вполне можно.* Вы знаете, что можно - в рамках поставленной задачи. Я знаю, что нельзя - в рамках выбранного автором пути решения задачи. Сейчас придёт его тимлид и даст решение вообще без открытия окна компроцессора. Кто правее? Впрочем, какая разница... не закрыли, и ладно. Интересно, сколько времени пройдёт до зелёной галки?

Comment: В конце концов, это моё личное, частное, мнение. Для того и требуется пять голосов, чтобы нивелировать возможную ошибку.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но что случилось? Тут прямо взрыв в комментах. Что не так, молодые люди?

Comment: @ВасёкНедопограмисть все спокойно, не на что тут смотреть :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У Process.Start есть перегрузка, позволяющая задать рабочую папку для запускаемого процесса (и еще много других параметров, включая перенаправление ввода-вывода и размеры окна).

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
{
    WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) 
});
```

Работает с любым процессом, а не только с cmd.exe.